# About shaping 2d dataframe to 3d by index

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to ask is there any function in pandas can reshape dataframe from 2d to 3d by it's index.

```
    col1  col2  col3
id                  
1      1     2     3
1      4     5     6
1      7     8     9
```

For example, I have 3 rows with the same id(+1 id row) each one has 3 cols,
drop the id and the dataframe is 1x3 (for each row), I want to make it (3x1x3)(by the same id). I tried groupby concat and join, but didn't work. Thanks

Comment: Can you include the expected output in the post.

Comment: why delete the sample data?

Comment: What you're trying to do is not really appropriate for pandas, but is very easy if you extract it into another library such as numpy. For example, would something like: `dat_3d = [np.stack(i)[:,None] for i in a.groupby('id').aggregate(list).values]` suffice?

Comment: pandas does not support dimensions greater than 2, but you can use [MultiIndexes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html)

Comment: Thanks jhso, that seems to be what I want, but the output became a list not an array, and cannot turn it into an array using np.asarray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the underlying numpy array:

```
r, c = df.shape
df.values.reshape(r, 1, c)
```

output:

```
array([[[1, 2, 3]],

       [[4, 5, 6]],

       [[7, 8, 9]]])
```

NB. if you want the other dimension: `df.values.T.reshape(c, 1, r)`